# Client API for FoundationDB

Tags: c++, flowlang, foundationdb

I was checking web site of the [FoundationDB](http://www.foundationdb.com). It says that it was developed on new programming language [Flow](http://www.flowlang.net). In websites it says :

> Flow is a new programming language design -- in fact an entirely new
>   programming language paradigm -- that solves the multicore dilemma
>   through ubiquitous, guaranteed-safe implicit parallelization.

The `code` itself eventually is being compiled to C++. 
What I am thinking about is that would it be possible to have C++ code inside Flow and would it be possible to reuse already existing C++ code/libs ?

Comment: There is now also Flow by Facebook

Answer (score 5):

There is a bit of confusion here. FoundationDB is built using a proprietary language called Flow, whereas your link to Flow (flowlang.net) is a different programming language. The naming is unfortunate, but understandable as FoundationDB's Flow (which I'll call FDBFlow) was started prior to Flow(lang), but not publicly disclosed.

In brief:

- Flowlang helps write *parallel code*
- FDBFlow helps write *concurrent code*